# Dropdown menu for style switcher

Tags: javascript, css, razor

I need to make a dropdownlist menu on my mvc model. The styleswitcher works correctly, as do the buttons:

```
<form>
            <input type="submit" onclick="switch_style('Ugly Default'); return false;" name="theme" value="Ugly_Default" id="Ugly_Default">
            <input type="submit" onclick="switch_style('Redmond'); return false;" name="theme" value="Redmond" id="Redmond">
</form>
```

The links are the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:57172/Content/site.css" title="Ugly_Default" >
     <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:57172/Content/Redmond.css" title="Redmond">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:57172/Scripts/styleswitcher.js"></script>
```

So far I've come up with this solution, which has no effect:

```
<form name="theme" id="theme" onsubmit="return false;">
        <select id="colourselector" name="theme" onchange="switch_style();">
            <option value="Ugly_Default">Default</option>
            <option value="Redmond">Redmond</option>
        </select>
</form>
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: the function 'switch_style' needs a parameter (style). You should rewrite it or create a new function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should to something like that :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#colourselector').on('change', function(){
    switch_style($(this).val());
  });
});
```

(Need Jquery)

Comment: Thanks man, it kinda works, but not universally. 
It only changes the theme to default.

The error on inspect element is:

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (about the line with $(document).ready(function () {   )

I have jQuery...

Comment: This error means that '$' is not defined. Means that Jquery is not included yet. The code I give should be place after included Jquery

Comment: You were correct. Thank you very much! I did in fact forget to include jQuery in the header, now it is working like a charm!

Comment: Please validate the answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression that I can't upvote = can't validate answers. Done now.

Comment: Once you have jquery loaded you can also just change the onchange statement that you have to "onchange="switch_style($(this).val());" --- edit but attaching event handlers through javascript is normally how it's done.